# After loading an activity, it sometimes works, sometimes not, why?

Tags: android, progress-bar, loading

I have a bit of a problem I cannot solve, since it might a bug or something like that. I would like to make a chart with androidplot, and it works really good, but of course it needs some time to draw it (using hundreds of data), so I use a progress dialog to indicate the loading. But what happens is really weird. 
I can define the appearance of the activity when it's loading and when it's loaded. When its loading I define a textview in the background setting its text to "loading" and if it is loaded, that textview contains lots of datas, text etc.

```
onCreate
{



        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {  
               public void run() {

-------what needs to be appeared after its loaded ----
Textview -> 12,3245,456,78,789

}

----what is on the screen while the progressbar is on---
TextView -> loading..
}
```

But most of the time after the progress dialog disappears, nothing happens, the textview still says "loading" and rarely it loads the datas and makes the data appear and changes the textview. What I noticed that the more data I would like to appear the rarelier it stays at the loading phase. Of course everytime the loading progessbar appeers then disappears. 
Any Suggestion?  It is really weird because I use it in a tablayout and other tabs never do this, always make the data appear.

Thanks in advance!

UP: Okay, its always the first tab, whatever it contains, so the first tab is somehow wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
The Andoid UI toolkit is not thread-safe. So, you must not manipulate your UI 
from a worker thread—you must do all manipulation to your user interface from
the UI thread. Thus, there are simply two rules to Android's single thread model:

1. Do not block the UI thread
2. Do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread
```

read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html) for more information on how to access UI elements from outside.
edit::

use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) ::

```
onCreate
{

     new myLoading().execute();    
}

class myLoading extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
     protected Void doInBackground(Void ... ) {
      .......... do all the loading here .........
     }
     protected void onPostExecute(Void ) {
        Textview -> 12,3245,456,78,789
     }
}
```

Comment: @JaniBela use either of these to update textView 1.Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable) [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29]
2.View.post(Runnable) [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29]
3.AysncTask [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out some workaround. I dont have any clue about the solution, my only guess is the loading screen somehow overtake the arrival of all the data and so the chart cannot be drawn. or whatever...
I put a thread.sleep(1000)  and now it works.